# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when using Iterator

Tags: java, mysql, spring, iterator, concurrentmodification

I am having a problem with this iterator on the set. This is a small project that I created with spring Initializer.

I use spring boot with tomcat. Previously I used a for loop and then I saw this answer over here [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing objects in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re) and tried to adapt the first answer to my case.

Only thing is is that I have to decouple the 2 entities Parent and Child from the bidirectional one-to-many, many-to-one relationship before deleting. I am still getting this error even if I use the iterator.

```
@PostMapping("/savecart")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveCartToDb(@RequestBody Set<CartProduct> cartProductList, Principal principal) {
        User logedInUser = userService.findUserByUsername(principal.getName()).get();

        Set<CartProduct> cartItemList = logedInUser.getCartProduct();

        for (CartProduct cartProduct : cartProductList) {
            cartProduct.setUser(logedInUser);
        }
        userService.saveNewUser(logedInUser);
        log.info("In saveCartToDb()");
        if (cartItemList.isEmpty()) {
            logedInUser.setCartProduct(cartProductList);
            userService.saveNewUser(logedInUser);
        } else {
            for (Iterator<CartProduct> iterator = cartItemList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                CartProduct cartItem = iterator.next();
                if (cartItem != null) {
                    // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
                    cartItem.dismissParent();
                    logedInUser.dismissChild(cartItem);
                    iterator.remove();
                    userService.saveNewUser(logedInUser);

                }
            }
//            for(CartProduct cartItem : cartItemList){
//                cartItem.dismissParent();
//                logedInUser.dismissChild(cartItem);
//                userService.saveNewUser(logedInUser);
//            }
            cartProductService.deleteAllProductIds();
            for (CartProduct cartProduct : cartProductList) {
                cartProduct.setUser(logedInUser);
            }
            logedInUser.setCartProduct(cartProductList);
            userService.saveNewUser(logedInUser);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(cartProductList.toString());
    }
```

The methods that I use to decouple

```
 public void dismissChild(CartProduct child) {
        this.cartProduct.remove(child);
    }

public void dismissParent() {
        this.user.dismissChild(this);
        this.user = null;
    }
```

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.remove(HashMap.java:1611) ~[na:na]
```

Is there a way I can modify the iterator no not receive this error anymore? Or is there a better solution that with the iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your exception

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.remove(HashMap.java:1611) [na:na]
```

So you have used a `HashMap` and you have received a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

But wait you don't have any `HashMap` in your code near the error correct?

You have `cartItemList.iterator()` and `cartItemList` is declared as `Set<CartProduct>`. Also the implementation which you have provided would be a `HashSet`.

But **`HashSet` is implemented behind the scenes from `java` using a `HashMap`**. Therefore the error that you have mentions a `HashMap`.

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

> public class **ConcurrentModificationException** extends RuntimeException
>
> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent
> modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify
> a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general,
> the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances.
> Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general
> purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to
> throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do
> this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and
> cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at
> an undetermined time in the future.
>
> **Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
> been concurrently modified by a different thread**. If a single thread
> issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of
> an object, the object may throw this exception. **For example, if a
> thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the
> collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this
> exception**.

`HashMap` and also `HashSet` provide a **fail-fast iterator**, meaning you are not allowed to modify the collection during iteration.

To solve your issue you **should avoid modifying the collection during** iteration.

So the following block of code

```
for (Iterator<CartProduct> iterator = cartItemList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                CartProduct cartItem = iterator.next();
                if (cartItem != null) {
                    // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
                    cartItem.dismissParent();
                    logedInUser.dismissChild(cartItem);
                    iterator.remove();
                    userService.saveNewUser(logedInUser);

                }
            }
```

Could be rewritten as

```
List<CartProduct> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList(); <-----------
for (Iterator<CartProduct> iterator = cartItemList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                CartProduct cartItem = iterator.next();
                if (cartItem != null) {
                    // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
                    cartItem.dismissParent();
                    logedInUser.dismissChild(cartItem);
                    toBeRemoved.add(cartItem);  <---------------
                    userService.saveNewUser(logedInUser);

                }
            }
cartItemList.removeAll(toBeRemoved); <--------
```

So you just gather all the elements during iteration that you need to remove and you invoke the removal only after iteration.